# Dynamically created buttons with equal alignment

Tags: delphi, button, dynamic, alignment, panel

I am a newbie to this Delphi. I have been given an assignment that to create buttons dynamically. But the problem is that all buttons have to be aligned in a manner that it should fit inside the whole screen. i.e, if 10 buttons created the whole screen should be filled. Or if 9 is given 9 should be present and filled in the screen. Is it possible to do that? I tried and searched everywhere. But was helpless.

Please help me if its possible. A good example is also appreciated since I mentioned earlier I am really new to this. The code I did follows here.

```
procedure TfrmMovieList.PnlMovieClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    B := TButton.Create(Self);
    B.Caption := Format('Button %d', [i]);
    B.Parent := Panel1;
    B.Height := 23;
    B.Width := 100;
    B.Left := 10;
    B.Top := 10 + i * 25;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is your code doing that you don't expect?

Comment: Nothing in this code accounts for the size of the panel that parents the buttons. Please note also that your original post was terribly formatted and made no attempt to use proper punctuation. That's fine for text messages, or twitter, but for programming there are higher standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks workable to me:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateButtons(aButtonsCount, aColCount: Integer; aDestParent: TWinControl);
var
  rowCount, row, col, itemWidth, itemHeight: Integer;
  item: TButton;
begin
  if aColCount>aButtonsCount then
    aColCount := aButtonsCount;
  rowCount := Ceil(aButtonsCount / aColCount);
  itemHeight := aDestParent.Height div rowCount;
  itemWidth := aDestParent.Width div aColCount;
  for row := 0 to rowCount-1 do begin
    for col := 0 to aColCount-1 do begin
      item := TButton.Create(Self);
      item.Caption := Format('Button %d', [(row*aColCount)+col+1]);
      item.Left := itemWidth*col;
      item.Top := itemHeight*row;
      item.Width := itemWidth;
      item.Height := itemHeight;
      item.Parent := aDestParent;
      Dec(aButtonsCount);
      if aButtonsCount=0 then
        Break;
    end; // for cols
  end; // for rows
end;
```

An example of usage is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateButtons(10, 4, Panel1);
end;
```

The function **Ceil** requires the uses of unit **Math**.

The method receives the count of buttons and the numbers of columns to calculate the number of rows. It also receives the destination parent where the buttons will be located.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. !!! That worked a lot for me ! You know what ? You are a saviour !!

Comment: Boss ! is it possible for me to show FilmNames in the dynamically created buttons or panels ? i.e , to run this query to show the FilmNames on dynamically created buttons ? QrySchedule.SQL.Add('select distinct FilmKey,FilmName from veu_ScheduleList where ShowDate='+
    QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('dd-mmm-yyyy',asdate)));

Comment: @user2269685: I guess it´s simple. You just have to add a new parameter to the method. This new parameter would be a vector with all the names you  want to set to the buttons. The method won´t know anything about the query, what makes it more reusable. If you change the method´s signature to receive such a parameter, you can dismiss the parameter aButtonsCount, since you will be able to know the buttons count by the length of the array.

Comment: Bro. One more thing ! Is there a way to align these dynamically created buttons or panels aligned at the centre ? My need is , if only one show there at a date it should come at the middle otherwise , if its aligned at the left it would not be a nice presentation know ? !!! Thanks in advance !

Comment: @user2269685: considering only what the method receives as parameters now, it´s not possible, because there isn´t any info about the size of the button. In order to get the behavior you described, the size of the single button or panel should be defined (extra parameters, for instance). If you decide to have a default size, than you can simply test to count of the buttons to create and, if it´s exactly 1, than use the default size and calculate it´s position to be the center of the containing control.

Comment: Hi again! Is there a way to align the dynamically created panels over another panel to be suited for all resolutions.Actually, when I change the resolution from 1280*768 to 1366*768 the alignment goes left oriented and not fit in the full screen.I already mentioned my need is to be fitted in full screen.For eg: I have dynamically created 28 buttons on 1280*768 resolution and if I change it to a lower resolution only 24 panels are shown at the screen.The rest have to be scrolled on. Please help dude !

Comment: And also is there a way to enable word wrap in dynamically created panel ? My need is to show the full film name if its big; in that panel. For eg: If the film name is The Good,the Bad and the Ugly ; it should be fitted on the panel. Or is there any alternative for that ? An eg: coding would be appreciated. Please help ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: Also ! I have been looking for a model program about Swipe card implementation for the payment of tickets in delphi. Can you please send me the link where I could get a sample coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SreenathKrishnakumar: the code I provided execute two processes required by the original question: creating the buttons and aligning them. You can study that code to create a new method to resize the buttons/panels according to the new resolution. About the other questions, I guess you will get better results if you post them as separate new questions instead comments. More people will see them and eventually give you good answers.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the valuable comments !